# Orbit of a symmetric matrix under orthogonal conjugation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, group-actions, symmetric-matrices

Let $A\in M_n(\Bbb{R} )$ be a symmetric matrix. I want to find a general formula for the diagonals of the matrices of the form $g^{-1}Ag$, where $g\in O_n(\Bbb{R})$.
Here is what I did : 
Since $A$ is symmetric, there is some $g\in O_n(\Bbb{R})$ such that $g^{-1}Ag$ is diagonal. Since similar matrices have the same trace, all the matrices in the orbit must have a trace equal to $\sum_{i=0}^k {n_i \lambda_i}$ where $\lambda_i$ are the eigenvalues of $A$ and $n_i$ their multiplicities.
My question is : Is every diagonal giving this trace in the orbit of $A$ or is there other restrictions ? And how to prove it?
$\mathbf{EDIT} :$ After the comments I got that helped me clarify a bit the situation, I want to continue a bit my thinking and formulate precisely what I need.
So far we have that the matrices in the orbit of $A$ must have the same trace $and $ the same eigenvalues. So it's a bit more complicated than thinking only about the trace. I'm still looking for a general formula for the diagonals of all the matrices in the orbit of $A$. Any idea would be very helpful.

Thank you

Comment: Consider the all-one matrix and the identity, or the matrix whose only nonzero entry is the upper-left one (which is $2$), so it is not always true.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying this. Do you have a way to find a formula for these diagonals ?

Comment: In an orbit, two elements should have same eigenvalues (with same multiplicities). Since they are symmetric, they are diagonalizable. So it's an "if and only if".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $A$ be a symmetric real $n\times n$ matrix with $spectrum(A)=(\lambda_i)$.

Then the orbit $\mathcal{O}_A$ of $A$, under the action $g\in O_n\mapsto g^{-1}Ag$, is the set of symmetric real matrices with the same spectrum as $A$.

Then the subset of $\mathcal{O}_A$ constituted by diagonal matrices has, up to a permutation -eventually with repetitions- of the entries of the diagonal, only one element: $diag(\lambda_1,\cdots,\lambda_n)$.

EDIT.  Majorization is a complete description of the relationships between the eigenvalues and diagonal entries of real symmetric matrices.

$\textbf{Definition}$. Let $(\lambda)=\lambda_n\leq \cdots\leq \lambda_1$, $(a)=a_n\leq\cdots \leq a_1$; we say that $(\lambda)$ majorizes $(a)$ iff for  every $k< n$, $\sum_{i=1}^k a_i\leq\sum_{i=1}^k \lambda_i$ and  $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i=\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i$.

$\textbf{Theorem}$ (cf. Horn and Johnson, Matrix Analysis).

If $(\lambda)$ majorizes $(a)$, then there is a symmetic real matrix $A$ s.t. $spectrum(A)=(\lambda)$ and its diagonal is $(a_i)$.

The converse of the previous theorem is true; that gives the required result, up to a permutation of the entries of the diagonal.

Comment: Thank you for your answer

Answer (score 1):

If $A$ is positive definite, so is $g^{-1}Ag$, and all the diagonal entries of these matrices will be positive.  So the trace condition alone cannot identify elements of the orbit.

For instance, the $2\times2$ identity matrix is symmetric, with trace $2$, but the diagonal $(3,-1)$ cannot occur in its orbit.

Comment: This seems more like a comment than an answer.

Comment: @Servaes I disagree: it is a short negative answer to the question  asked.  When the question changes and becomes more nuanced, I will change the answer accordingly.